# Convert a [Drink] object array into a json object to save to Firebase DB in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Objective: I have an array of `[Drink]` and wish to save them to Firebase RDBS under their `posId`. So that the Firebase saved tree structure would look something like this:

```
-drinks
-----posID-1
--------name
--------description
--------unitPrice
--------tags
-----------tag1
-----------tag2
```

Model class `Drink`

```
class Drink {

    var posId: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var tags: [String]?
    var unitPrice: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {


        self.posId = dictionary["posId"] as? String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.description = dictionary["description"] as? String
        self.unitPrice = dictionary["unitPrice"] as? String
        self.tags = dictionary["tags"] as? [String]


    }//end init

}//end class
```

function which maps `[Drink]` array to a `Dictionary` and prints output to console

```
func loadDrinks(){

            print("drinksOrder count:\(drinksOrder.count)")

            let drinksOrdered = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: drinksOrder.map {($0.posId, $0.self)})
            print(drinksOrdered)

 }//end func
```

output:

> [Optional("0009372"): vipeeps.Drink, Optional("0009373"):
>   vipeeps.Drink, Optional("0009374"): vipeeps.Drink]

**Question: How can I further map the Drink object into a Dictionary key:value structure required to save to Firebase?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to convert it to JSON like the question title says, you can use the [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol (or typealias for `Decodable & Encodable`. It makes it really easy to convert between models and json and back.

Here is a unit test example to demonstrate both ways. I switched it to a struct just to get the free init to make it shorter and `Equatable` is not required, only added to do the comparison in the second unit test.

```swift
import XCTest

struct Drink: Codable, Equatable {
    var posId: String?
    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var tags: [String]?
    var unitPrice: String?
}

class CodableDrink: XCTestCase {
    func testCreateJSONFromDrink() {
        let drink = Drink(posId: "1", name: "Monster", description: "Nasty Energy Drink", tags: ["energy", "caffeine"], unitPrice: "$1.89")
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        let encodedData = try! encoder.encode(drink)
        let jsonString = String(data: encodedData, encoding: .utf8)!
        XCTAssertEqual(jsonString, """
        {"tags":["energy","caffeine"],"unitPrice":"$1.89","name":"Monster","posId":"1","description":"Nasty Energy Drink"}
        """)
    }
    func testCreateDrinkFromJSON() {
        let json = """
        {"tags":["energy","caffeine"],"unitPrice":"$1.89","name":"Monster","posId":"1","description":"Nasty Energy Drink"}
        """
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let drink = try! decoder.decode(Drink.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
        XCTAssertEqual(drink, Drink(posId: "1", name: "Monster", description: "Nasty Energy Drink", tags: ["energy", "caffeine"], unitPrice: "$1.89"))
    }
}
```

[This documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) is also very helpful and shows how to do extra things like handling when you want your variable name and the key in the json to be different or how to manually encode and decode instead of using the automatic behavior.

Comment: so if I have an array of `[Drink]` objects how can I convert into say json object to save to Firebase?

Comment: @Roggie I dont know the specifics of what Firebase wants but if you just need json the linked documentation states "Built-in types such as Array, Dictionary, and Optional also conform to Codable whenever they contain codable types." This means that if `Drink` is `Codable`, then `[Drink]` is also `Codable` and can be converted to json the same say that `Drink` can. So in the first test in my example you could replace the `drink` variable with an array of drinks, pass it into  `encoder.encode` the same way, and then `jsonString` will now be a string containing a json array of json drink objects.